# Skeletal animation using parsed data from COLLADA file in Three.js

Tags: animation, webgl, three.js, collada

I have experimented with the example COLLADA parser colladaloader.js and imported a skeletal animated collada model "Seymour_anim2.dae" from http://collada.org/owl/browse.php?sess=0&parent=131&expand=0&order=name&curview=0 using mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html and http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_animation_skinning.html as an example. The loader seems to parse and store the skeleton structure and some skeletal animation data either in collada.animations or collada.dae.animations. The problem is that I can't get the skeletal animation to work using the methods in the examples.

Now, I'm wondering is there something wrong with the COLLADA parser, or are there some other methods/tricks in Three.js that could be used to play the skeletal animation of my model?  I'd love to hear if you have any ideas how this could be done neatly in Three.js or is this even possible yet.

**Edit:** I have now also tested the model with GLGE framework and it loads, renders and animates it correctly. However, it would be very good to have skeletal animation for COLLADA  model in Three.js because developing with GLGE is too time consuming and troublesome and GLGE is quite inactive project compared to Three.js. Skeletal animations are important for increasing immersion in a virtual world.

Comment: Did you try all of the tips mentioned in the last post of this forum?
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2106#issuecomment-9735541

Answer (score 0):

I've myself given up on Collada and went on using the included OBJ loader.
But halfway through I've found one thing that might be worth testing out.
There seems to be an alternative Collada loader, here: [github ColladaLoader2.coffee](https://github.com/rmx/threejs-collada/blob/master/ColladaLoader2.coffee)

Hopefully it works somewhat better. Please let me know :)